# Position overlay div

Tags: css

I have a link in a table cell and when the link is clicked I show a hidden div.

Currently I use position: absolute and z-index:10. It works fine, but I would like to move it a bit to the top and left. When I add top: -10px and left: -10px, the div moves to the position of the window.

How do I make it 10px off the table cell?

Answer (score 11):

You need to **set the parent element using position relative then use position absolute on the element you want to position**. So if you want it to be positioned based on the table you need to add position: relative to the table (which won't do anything because it is already positioned relative) and position: absolute to the overlay. Absolute positioning takes the element out of the document flow and relative positioning leaves it in the document flow which is why stuff is being moved around. The reason for this is based off how CSS works: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp

**relative**    The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position

**absolute**    The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

You might also be interested in fixed.

**fixed**   The element is positioned relative to the browser window

**Here is an Example**: http://pastehtml.com/view/av391nzsv.html

Comment: OK... So how do I reference the <TD> where the div is "hiding"? In jQuery I can probably do something like $(this).parent(); but I'm still not very clear... Could you give an example, please? W3schools' example references the top/left of the page.

Comment: if you want it to overlay the table you need to set position: relative on the table. then on the element (the td it sounds like) you want to actually move around and position, set position: absolute and use top/bottom/left/right to move it into position. i would make an example for you but i'm currently at work. I can make one when i get home in a couple hours if you still need it.

Comment: if you linked the site it would probably be easier to explain as well.

Comment: It is not on a site yet. I'm writing code on a local machine now. And yes, I would really appreciate an example.

Comment: http://pastehtml.com/view/av391nzsv.html sorry it took so long. cats decided to eat my speakers while i was at work.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: relative;
```

instead of

```
position: absolute;
```

Relative says to measure top and left from the parent element, absolute says to measure from the top left corner of the page.

Comment: That's what I started with but for some reason it pushes my table cell when it becomes visible...

Answer (score 0):

use `margin-top:-10px; margin-left:-10px;`